# Interpolation hourly to half hourly in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have data frame named "load_demand" consists of hourly electricity demand which grouped by day from year 2018 to 2022.  Below are details about the data frame "load_demand":

```
dput(head(load_demand))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17532, 17533, 17534, 17535, 
17536, 17537), class = "Date"), HR1 = c(617.3, 611.9, 621.6, 
651.4, 639, 653.9), HR2 = c(589.4, 578.8, 600.3, 622.6, 624.4, 
631.3), HR3 = c(556.1, 569.9, 579.1, 610.6, 611.1, 612.9), HR4 = c(566.3, 
558.8, 580.1, 592, 600, 607.3), HR5 = c(563.4, 573.1, 589.8, 
598.4, 591.6, 608.5), HR6 = c(551.8, 597, 609.2, 624.4, 622, 
601), HR7 = c(523.6, 577.1, 578.5, 605.3, 592.8, 582), HR8 = c(520.7, 
638.5, 647.1, 671.9, 674.8, 606.8), HR9 = c(542.5, 729, 732.3, 
745.7, 760.1, 659.1), HR10 = c(589, 797.4, 796.2, 811.9, 821.4, 
719.7), HR11 = c(617, 815.2, 818.1, 840.7, 845.6, 743.2), HR12 = c(611.3, 
796.8, 792.2, 813.5, 820.7, 723.1), HR13 = c(617.9, 785, 800.6, 
806.1, 810.2, 712.9), HR14 = c(620.7, 822, 840.3, 832.2, 829.8, 
733.4), HR15 = c(624.6, 840.4, 846.6, 854.3, 859.1, 714.9), HR16 = c(631.3, 
833.9, 825.5, 854, 853.9, 702), HR17 = c(632.2, 789.1, 778.1, 
806, 770.1, 694.9), HR18 = c(689.1, 776.8, 794.6, 788.4, 793.9, 
723.4), HR19 = c(758.3, 831.2, 843, 848, 836.6, 785.7), HR20 = c(756.6, 
799.6, 831.5, 826.1, 819.2, 763.2), HR21 = c(744.7, 781.2, 812.3, 
807.1, 784.6, 736.8), HR22 = c(713.7, 734.2, 764.4, 761.5, 748.2, 
677.6), HR23 = c(686.1, 713.6, 732.9, 720.1, 730.6, 673.9), HR24 = c(637.8, 
657.2, 688.9, 676.8, 676.7, 643)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to interpolate the data in column 2:25 which are column named "HR1" to column "HR24" from hourly to half hourly data into a new data frame named halfhourly_load which maintain the first column "Date" and create 48 load columns where each columns from 2:49 are named

```
c("HR0030", "HR0100", "HR0130", "HR0200", "HR0230", "HR0300", 
"HR0330", "HR0400", "HR0430", "HR0500", "HR0530", "HR0600", "HR0630", 
"HR0700", "HR0730", "HR0800", "HR0830", "HR0900", "HR0930", "HR1000", 
"HR1030", "HR1100", "HR1130", "HR1200", "HR1230", "HR1300", "HR1330", 
"HR1400", "HR1430", "HR1500", "HR1530", "HR1600", "HR1630", "HR1700", 
"HR1730", "HR1800", "HR1830", "HR1900", "HR1930", "HR2000", "HR2030", 
"HR2100", "HR2130", "HR2200", "HR2230", "HR2300", "HR2330", "HR2400")
```

"HR" is a 24-hour clock such as "HR1" equal to 01:00AM, and "HR24" is 00:00AM for that particular load recorded. So, in the new data frame, "HR0030" means 00:30am which is an interpolated value of "HR24" from previous day and "HR1" from current day.

Comment: Try `dput(head(load_demand))` and format as code when sharing your data.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to maintain the date column but want half hourly data? By doubling the columns, the expected output is *`original_col` followed by `interpolated_col`* for each of the original columns?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, I want to maintain the same data format but with half hourly data. Original data frame consists of 24 hour recorded data for load demand, for a new data frame I need it to consists of 48 half hourly data of every 30 minutes load_demand data. Sorry for my english as I am not native english speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. Use base function `approx` to linearly interpolate each row vector of the data set, disregarding the date column, only the hours columns matter.
The value for `"HR0030"` needs to be extrapolated. Compute the slope and y intercept for the first two values of the vector, since the first half hour is outside the `x` range and `approx` only interpolates.

```r
finterp <- function(y, x, col_names = new_col_names) {
  out <- approx(x, y, xout = x - 0.5)
  m <- diff(y[1:2])/diff(x[1:2])
  b <- y[1] - m*x[1]
  out$y[1] <- m*0.5 + b
  ynew <- numeric(length(col_names))
  ynew[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- y
  ynew[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- out$y
  setNames(ynew, col_names)
}

i_cols <- grep("H", names(load_demand))
halfhourly_load <- t(apply(load_demand[i_cols], 1, finterp, x = seq_along(i_cols)))

halfhourly_load <- cbind(load_demand["Date"], halfhourly_load)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Though not asked here is a function that uses linear regression of the row vectors on hour to predict the half hour values.
Just like above, the function is `apply`'ed to each row to get the new half hourly values.

```r
flm <- function(y, x, col_names = new_col_names) {
  fit <- lm(y ~ x, data.frame(x, y))
  ypred <- predict(fit, data.frame(x = x - 0.5))
  ynew <- numeric(length(col_names))
  ynew[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- y
  ynew[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- ypred
  setNames(ynew, col_names)
}

i_cols <- grep("H", names(load_demand))
halfhourly_load_lm <- t(apply(load_demand[i_cols], 1, flm, x = seq_along(i_cols)))
halfhourly_load_lm <- cbind(load_demand["Date"], halfhourly_load_lm)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The new column names vector is missing from the code above.

```r
new_col_names <- c("HR0030", "HR0100", "HR0130", "HR0200", "HR0230", "HR0300", 
                   "HR0330", "HR0400", "HR0430", "HR0500", "HR0530", "HR0600", "HR0630", 
                   "HR0700", "HR0730", "HR0800", "HR0830", "HR0900", "HR0930", "HR1000", 
                   "HR1030", "HR1100", "HR1130", "HR1200", "HR1230", "HR1300", "HR1330", 
                   "HR1400", "HR1430", "HR1500", "HR1530", "HR1600", "HR1630", "HR1700", 
                   "HR1730", "HR1800", "HR1830", "HR1900", "HR1930", "HR2000", "HR2030", 
                   "HR2100", "HR2130", "HR2200", "HR2230", "HR2300", "HR2330", "HR2400")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I try to run this code, its return me "Error in numeric(length(col_names)) : object 'new_col_names' not found". I am sorry, I don't understand what its mean since I am still learning to code with R.

Comment: @NickHK Sorry, I forgot to put it in the answer. `'new_col_names` is the vector of new column names you have posted in the question. I will edit the answer to include it. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be quicker than Rui's solution, as it avoids loops. Also our `0030` times are different, as i interpolate between `0024` and `0010`.

```
l <- as.matrix(load_demand[-1])
o <- as.numeric(t(l))
s <- c(o[1], o[-length(o)])
i <- matrix((o+s)/2, ncol=24, byrow=TRUE)
n <- rbind(i, l)
dim(n) <- dim(n)*c(0.5, 2)

hr <- head(sprintf("HR%02d%02d", rep(0:24, each=2), c(0, 30))[-1], -1)
colnames(n) <- hr

load_demand_i <- data.frame(load_demand[,1], n)    
load_demand_i[1:6, 1:9]

#         Date HR0030 HR0100 HR0130 HR0200 HR0230 HR0300 HR0330 HR0400
# 1 2018-01-01 617.30  617.3 603.35  589.4 572.75  556.1 561.20  566.3
# 2 2018-01-02 624.85  611.9 595.35  578.8 574.35  569.9 564.35  558.8
# 3 2018-01-03 639.40  621.6 610.95  600.3 589.70  579.1 579.60  580.1
# 4 2018-01-04 670.15  651.4 637.00  622.6 616.60  610.6 601.30  592.0
# 5 2018-01-05 657.90  639.0 631.70  624.4 617.75  611.1 605.55  600.0
# 6 2018-01-06 665.30  653.9 642.60  631.3 622.10  612.9 610.10  607.3
```